# Scaling two different imgsto fit the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to scale two images to fit a mobile screen with both keeping their original proportions without overflow. When I've tried to apply max-width it only kicks in when one image falls below screen width.

```css
.one img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.two img {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Distribution_H._leucocephalus.png"></div>
<div class="two"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg/800px-Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried media queries?

Comment: I need both images to remain on the same line and to scale so both retain shape and fit the screen

Answer (score 1):

**Try**:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
}

.slider .slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Distribution_H._leucocephalus.png" style="max-width: 200px;">
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg/800px-Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg"
      style="max-width: 300px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. I need both images to stay on the same line

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this:**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.one img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.two img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Distribution_H._leucocephalus.png"></div>
  <div class="two"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg/800px-Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.one, .two {
  width:50%; float:left
}
.one img, .two img { 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="one"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Distribution_H._leucocephalus.png"></div>
<div class="two"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fe/Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg/800px-Back_to_the_Six_Mile_Lake_eagles_%28Haliaeetus_leucocephalus%29.%22feed_me_mom%22._%2819159890706%29.jpg"></div>
```

Can you please check this and let me know, if this is the same you are looking for.